# Redirect to confirmation state of drupal 7 form with php

Tags: php, forms, callback, drupal-7

Drupal 7

I have a taxonomy term "companies", which is being used by content type "contacts".

When the delete button of my taxonomy term form for companies is clicked, code checks if there are contacts connected to the to be deleted term.

If connected contacts are found the below altered taxonomy confirm form is shown.

[altered confirm form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jSsF.png)

When edit is clicked, users go to the contact node form and can connect the contact to another company term. When submit is clicked in the node form, I want to return to the confirm state of the taxonomy term form (so to the above image). It now redirects with the following code, but this of course doesn't redirect to the confirm state of the form.

```
function theme_redirect_to_specific_company($form, &$form_state) {      
    unset($_GET['destination']);    
    $triggerdElement = $form_state['triggering_element'];
    $debtor = $triggerdElement['#company']; 
    $redirect_url = '/taxonomy/term/'.$debtor.'/edit';
    $form_state['redirect'] = $redirect_url; 
}
```

I can achieve to redirect to the confirm state of the form with jquery (delete button click), but is this also possible with php?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you
you can use rules module events like

Events:-

After deleting a term

After updating an existing term

Action:-
use Execute custom PHP code

```
$options = array('query' => array('foo' => $_GET['foo'], 'bar' => $_GET['bar']));
drupal_set_message(t("Set your message"));
drupal_goto('/yourpath/'.$_GET['foobar'],$options);
```